# UITableViewCell not deselecting when willDisplay function is implemented

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` which displays several available options for the user to choose from. What I want is for the table to always reflect the options that are selected, which are stored in an array that is part of a class separate from that of the view controller. I am attempting to have the selected options displayed when the table loads by using the `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` method. The problem that I am having is that when I implement this method, any option that is in the array when the table loads does NOT deselect when pressed. Code is as follows:

```
class Options {
    enum Option : String {
        case option1 = "Option 1"
        case option2 = "Option 2"
        case option3 = "Option 3"
        case option4 = "Option 4"
        case option5 = "Option 5"
        case option6 = "Option 6"
        case option7 = "Option 7"
    }
    static let allOptions : [Option] = [.option1, .option2, .option3, .option4, .option5, .option6, .option7]
    static var selectedOptions : [Option] = [.option2, .option7]
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var optionsTableView: UITableView!

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return Options.allOptions.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = Options.allOptions[indexPath.row].rawValue
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        Options.selectedOptions.append(Options.allOptions[indexPath.row])
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let option = Options.allOptions[indexPath.row]
        for o in Options.selectedOptions {
            if option == o {
                let i = Options.selectedOptions.index(of: o)!
                Options.selectedOptions.remove(at: i)
            }
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let option = Options.allOptions[indexPath.row]
        if Options.selectedOptions.contains(option) {
            cell.setSelected(true, animated: false)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.optionsTableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
        self.optionsTableView.delegate = self
        self.optionsTableView.dataSource = self
    }

}
```

Comment: Create a model Option with name and isSelected properties. Then manipulate isSelected property on basis of selection. Use allOption: [Option] as model for table. You don't need separate models allOption and selectedOption.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't follow. What do you mean "model"?

Comment: I mean use a struct Option { name: String, isSelected: Bool} then toggle isSelected whenever user selects or deselects option at didSelectRowAt and then reload. You don't need willDisplay or didDeselectRowAt.

Answer (score 5):

`cell.setSelected(true, animated: false)`is not actually selecting the cell in tableview. It is callback after the cell is selected. Instead, you have to call 
`tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)`

Your willDisplay function should be:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let option = Options.allOptions[indexPath.row]
    if Options.selectedOptions.contains(option) {
        tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
    }
}
```

Comment: please add more explanation

Comment: It seems that the setSelected function disabled to delegate functions didSelect and didDeselect.

Comment: @mightknow if it is solution for you, can you accept my answer? Thank you.