# iOS Set UITableViewCell.isSelected to true, causes delegate methods not getting called

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates

This is the sample project for my question.
https://github.com/KeDaQHR/TableViewCell.isSelected

Basically I set:

```
tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
```

Then I tap the Deselect button at bottom, which will reload the tableview and do this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  if shoudSelect {
    cell.setSelected(true, animated: true)
  }
}
```

which will make all cell to be selected. Then if I tap a cell, none of the delegates methods like willSelectRowAt, didSelectRowAt, didDeselectRowAt will get called.

If I replace

```
cell.setSelected(true, animated: true)
```

with

```
tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
```

It will work fine. Any one knows why the delegates methods are not responsive in the first case? Thanks!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53587360/uitableviewcell-not-deselecting-when-willdisplay-function-is-implemented

Comment: @rmaddy how come it affects the UITableView's delegates?

Comment: Interesting find. Setting setSelect(false) does not have the same effect and delegate methods continue to work. Seems to be a mishap on Apple's part